# Searching a cell array of vectors and returning indices

Tags: matlab, search, vector, cell-array

I have a 3000x1 `cell` array of vectors of different lengths and am looking for a way to search them all for a number and return the `cell` indices for the first and last occurrence of that number.

So my data looks like this:

```
[1]
[1 2]
[1 2]
[3]
[6 7 8 9]
etc
```

And I want to my results to look like this when I search for the number 1:

```
ans = 1   3
```

All the indices (e.g. `[1 2 3]` for 1) would also work, though the above would be better. So far I'm unable to solve either problem.

I've tried

```
cellfun(@(x) x==1, positions, 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

This returns a logical array, effectively putting me back at square 1. I've tried using `find(cellfun...)` but this gives the error `undefined function 'find' for input arguments of type 'cell'`. Most of the help I can find is for searching for strings within a cell array. Do I need to convert all my vectors to strings for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C = {[1]
[1 2]
[1 2]
[3]
[6 7 8 9]}; %// example data

N = 1; %// sought number

ind = cellfun(@(v) any(v==N), C); %// gives 1 for cells which contain N
first = find(ind,1);
last = find(ind,1,'last');
result = [ first last ];
```